# From where does the Lebesgue measure act?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

That's probably a stupid question, but I can't find from where does the Lebesgue measure acts.

It is said Lebesgue measure is a standard continuation of Jordan measure:
$$\phi : P^n \to [0, +\infty]$$, where $P^n$ is a set of all, let's call them cells, i.e $[a_1, b_1) \times[a_2, b_2) \times \dotso \times [a_n, b_n)$ and $a_i, b_i \in R$.

So the set from where the Lebesgue measure acts, let's denote it as $M \supset P^n$, since it is continuation.

However, all the resources that I found on the Internet, only say that Lebesgue measure is a continuation, but don't give this set $M$ explicitly.

I would be glad if someone could give me the explicit definition of Lebesgue measure, i.e in form $f: A \to B$.

And if you have something to add in general you're welcome.

Comment: It acts on the set of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$, which is a proper (assuming the Axiom of Choice) subset of $2^{\mathbb R}$ and a proper superset of the set of [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set). One way to characterize/define this set is to first define [Lebesgue outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Definition), and then define the set of Lebesgue measurable sets to be precisely those which satisfy the [Caratheodory criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carathéodory%27s_criterion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr Bungo's remarks are correct , I'll add that the Borel sets can be defined to be the intersection of all sigma algebra's containing all the cells ;where a sigma algebra is a collection of subsets that are closed under the formation of countable unions and complements . A set of Lebesgue measure zero can be defined as a set that can be covered by a countable number of cells ,the sum of whose Jordan measures is as small as desired . Then the set M is the collection of unions of a Borel set and a set of Lebesgue measure zero .